# How to share data from a collection belongs to a particular customer in Azure cosmos db?

Tags: powerbi, azure-cosmosdb

I have a requirement to share data stored in azure cosmos db with customers. All customers data is stored in various collections. We would like to give read access to data belongs to respective customer only. So that one customer can only access his/her data and not of others from collections.

We would like to integrate this customer specific data with PowerBI in next step.

Could anyone suggest way(s) to give customer specific read access of their data from Azure cosmos db?

From what I was able to find below were the possible options. Though none seem to be fulfilling the requirement.

- Master keys - which would give access to whole database and would give access to whole database, which is not desired.
- By creating admin users - which is not desired.
- By using Resource token - This is time bound and would have limited lifetime.

It would be helpful if anyone could add further insight on same to fulfill the  requirement.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since you tagged this question as C# im assuming you are considering code as a solution ? Why not write an api that exposes the information , then you can do Authentication and Authorization for individual clients and restrict who can see what?

Comment: Thanks for prompt response. Certainly, that can be an option. Though, we would like to use this customer specific cosmos db data with PowerBI. So looking for ways to share data from cosmos db.

Comment: Have a look at RLS (Row Level Security). All reports are same and customer gets filtered to his own data based on login. Other option is Dataflows, you make a dataflow per customer and give him explicit data. Customer can use this data to make own reports.

Comment: Thanks @Aldert! Sure, i will look into these. If you can share relevant links to follow would be really helpful..